# Nested if else statement in R with multiple string in each cell

Tags: r, if-statement, nested

I would like to do an if else statement with multiple conditions.
I have two data frames, first one looks like this:

```
prefix <- "sample"
suffix <- seq(1:100)
id <- paste(prefix, suffix, sep="")
indv_df <- data.frame(id, count = matrix(ncol=1, nrow=100))
```

And the first 15 rows of indv_df looks like this:

```
           id count
1     sample1    NA
2     sample2    NA
3     sample3    NA
4     sample4    NA
5     sample5    NA
6     sample6    NA
7     sample7    NA
8     sample8    NA
9     sample9    NA
10   sample10    NA
11   sample11    NA
12   sample12    NA
13   sample13    NA
14   sample14    NA
15   sample15    NA
```

The second table called row1 that I have looks like this:

```
 Hom <- paste("sample2", "sample3", "sample4", sep=",")
 Het <- paste("sample5", "sample6", "sample7", sep=",")
 Missing <- paste("sample10", "sample11", sep=",")
 row1 <- data.frame(Hom, Het, Missing)
```

looks like this:

```
                      Hom                     Het           Missing
1 sample2,sample3,sample4 sample5,sample6,sample7 sample10,sample11
```

I am trying to do if else statement that if the first row's id does not match any of the second table's content, write "0" in the first table's first row, second column. This is what I tried but didn't work, which I am not too surprised since this is my first if else statement. I know it should be straight forward but I tried a few different methods none worked

```
> if(grep(indv_df$id[1], row1$Hom)){
+   apply(indv_df[1,2]=="2")
+ } else if(grep(indv_df$id[1], row1$Het)){
+   apply(indv_df[1,2]=="1")
+ } else if(grep(indv_df$id[1], row1$Missing)){
+   apply(indv_df[1,2]=="missing")
+ } else (apply(indv_df[1,2]=="0"))
```

this is the error message I got:

```
Error in if (grep(indv_df$id[1], row1$Hom)) { : 
  argument is of length zero
```

The real dataset has 4 million rows in the second data.frame, so I am just testing the first step..... once I get through this I will try to do that in a loop for all rows. :D Thank you for all the help in advance.

Comment: You should use grepl instead of grep. For if statement, you need to have a boolean value.

Comment: Thanks @TruongNhatMinh, I just googled the difference and realized that "grep" returns numeric values that correspond to the indexed locations of the patterns and "grepl" returns a logical vector in which “TRUE” represents a pattern match.

Comment: The way you're using grep may cause issues if your value of `row1$Hom` is `sample200,sample3105,sample4078`. Assuming you only want rows where `id` is `sample200`, `sample3105`, or `sample4078`, you'll get false matches on `sample2`, `sample20`, `sample3`, `sample31`, etc. Splitting on the comma and matching will avoid this problem.

Comment: Thanks @EricWatt I was wondering if grep is specific for the string. Glad you mentioned it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues that might be impacting you. Your eventual result will have a character column for the `count` column. It's best to do this up front, and would be clearer than how you currently have it done.

```
indv_df <- data.frame(id, count = NA_character_)
```

However, using your data.frame as you constructed it, I would approach this not by a series of `if` statements, but by subsetting. In addition, you have lines like `apply(indv_df[1,2]=="missing")`. This is wrong for a few reasons. `indv_df[1,2]` is more matrix syntax, and returns an NA. Then you check for identity with `==`, rather than assigning a value.

Here is a solution using `data.frame` syntax, and the `stringr` library.

```
library(stringr)
indv_df$count <- as.character(indv_df$count)
indv_df$count <- "0"
indv_df[indv_df$id %in% unlist(str_split(as.character(row1$Hom), ",")),]$count <- "2"
indv_df[indv_df$id %in% unlist(str_split(as.character(row1$Het), ",")),]$count <- "1"
indv_df[indv_df$id %in% unlist(str_split(as.character(row1$Missing), ",")),]$count <- "missing"
#          id   count
# 1   sample1       0
# 2   sample2       2
# 3   sample3       2
# 4   sample4       2
# 5   sample5       1
# 6   sample6       1
# 7   sample7       1
# 8   sample8       0
# 9   sample9       0
# 10 sample10 missing
# 11 sample11 missing
# 12 sample12       0
# 13 sample13       0
# 14 sample14       0
# 15 sample15       0
```

Personally, I prefer `data.table` syntax for this.

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
setDT(indv_df)
setDT(row1)
indv_df[, count := as.character(count)]
indv_df[, count := "0"]
indv_df[id %in% unlist(str_split(as.character(row1$Hom), ",")), count := "2"]
indv_df[id %in% unlist(str_split(as.character(row1$Het), ",")), count := "1"]
indv_df[id %in% unlist(str_split(as.character(row1$Missing), ",")), count := "missing"]
#           id   count
#  1:  sample1       0
#  2:  sample2       2
#  3:  sample3       2
#  4:  sample4       2
#  5:  sample5       1
#  6:  sample6       1
#  7:  sample7       1
#  8:  sample8       0
#  9:  sample9       0
# 10: sample10 missing
# 11: sample11 missing
# 12: sample12       0
# 13: sample13       0
# 14: sample14       0
# 15: sample15       0
```

Comment: Thank you, it is very helpful. I am not familiar with data.table syntax other than fread. Do you have any suggestions for fast reading files that's 80GB and i only have 8GB of memory. I do have access to cluster just that it has not been stable lately.. thanks.

Comment: Speed is probably less of an issue than simply not having enough RAM to keep the table in memory. Do you need all of the columns? You can use `select` or `drop` parameters in `fread` to choose a subset of columns to keep or remove. This would be helpful if your file had many columns but you only needed a few. How many rows is your data?

Comment: The file has 4 columns and 4.69 million rows. Maybe I could just chunk the dataset into 10 files and process them? I agree RAM is a limitation.....

Comment: Yeah, if your analysis can be done in sections, splitting it up by rows is probably the way to go. Or get more RAM :)